# jQuery tabs not working in IE6-7

Tags: jquery, tabs

I´m using some jQuery to make tabs on this page:
http://johandahl.com/wp/malmocityfastigheter/ekonomi/

But, they are not working in internet explorer 6-7. The tabbed areas doesnt hide and are just stacked beneth each other. Any ideas what could be wrong here?

This is what my jQuery code looks like:

```
/* TABS */
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
// For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
// which tab is active and it's associated content
var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

// Use the first link as the initial active tab
$active = $links.first().addClass('active');
$content = $($active.attr('href'));

// Hide the remaining content
$links.not(':first').each(function () {
$($(this).attr('href')).hide();
});

// Bind the click event handler
$(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
// Make the old tab inactive.
$active.removeClass('active');
$content.hide();

// Update the variables with the new link and content
$active = $(this);
$content = $($(this).attr('href'));

// Make the tab active.
$active.addClass('active');
$content.show();

// Prevent the anchor's default click action
e.preventDefault();
});
});
});
```

Here is a sample of the html for this:

```
            <ul class='tabs'>
                <li><a href='#beskrivning'>Om adressen</a></li>             
                <li><a href='#aktuellt'>Aktuell information</a></li>
            </ul>

        <div class="entry-about">           
            <div id='beskrivning'>

            </div>


            <div id='aktuellt'>

            </div>


        </div>
```

Comparing IE and Chrome for example shows that in Chrome the inline styles of "display: block; " and display: none; " are added correctly to my tabbed areas. But in IE Developer Tools, no such styles are added - yet there is no error in my jQuery either. Ideas?????

Comment: Do you get any JS error in those browsers? Is JS enabled in them?

Comment: I´m not actually able to test the page in those browsers at the moment because I´m not on a windows machine. I noticed this by looking at page screenshots http://netrenderer.com/.

If someone else reading this is able to look at it I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: The code looks good other than the missing `});` at the end which is more than likely a copy paste error. I would next look at the HTML to make sure that everything is properly opened and closed.

Comment: Yeah, that was just a copy paste error. I added a sample of the html to my posts, can anyone see anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i managed to find what was wrong. If anyone is curious, it was some kind of conflict with modernizr.js. My page seems to render properly without modernizr so I´m removing it.